# How to fire fault for a relationship of a Managed Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This is the model I am working with:
`CourseProgram <--->> Student --->> Grades`

When I fetch from Core Data my Course Program managed object, it returns Student properly but Grades as a relationship fault.

I understand that Core Data return Relationships Faults to reduce overhead. According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW2), I can use `setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:` to force the Core Data to return the managed object instead of faults.

I tried and it didn't work. I cannot fetch Grades as a managed object whenever I execute a fetch request for Course Programs. How do I fire fault for a relationship?

This is the code I use to fetch the Course Programs objects

```
// Fetch from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"CoursePrograms"];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:YES];

NSArray *coursePrograms = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
return coursePrograms;
```

Comment: Why do you want to? And can you show the code that "didn't work"?

Comment: @jrturton updated with my code

Comment: Ok, and why do you want to do this? Depending on your object graph, pre-fetching all relationships could fetch every single object into memory at once

Comment: I need the grades to be loaded so that I can archiving and send the data. In any case, the _number of rows_ for Course Programs would be limited, no more than 20, so I guess it wouldn't hurt the performance badly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry about the relationships coming back as faults. Just access them via the relationship of the objects you do get, and the faults will be fired (converted to full objects) for you.

If you have an array of course programs returned from your fetch request, you can iterate through the `students`, then iterate through each student's grades. It won't make a difference if they're fetched as faults or not, you'll still get the data.

I've written about common misconceptions about faulting [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/04/24/its-not-your-fault/) if you're interested.

Comment: This is flat out wrong. Right now I'm testing an app where accessing the relationship faults does nothing. They do NOT fire.

Comment: Accessing the fault does nothing, accessing the _properties_ of the related object fires the fault. The main point is, you shouldn't care. Faulting happens for a reason and it never stops you seeing the data you want.